# Python django foreign key (1048, "Column 'USER_ID' cannot be null")

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have two models, one is `UsersModel` model, the other one is `address_add`. I want to create a relation between `UsersModel` and `address_add` with USER_ID field. Finally, I created the template and after pressing the save button I have got this error.

(1048, "Column 'USER_ID' cannot be null")

Here is my `UsersModel`.

```
class UsersModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    USER_ID = models.AutoField(_('USER_ID'), primary_key=True,)
    USER_COMPANY_NAME = models.CharField(_('USER_COMPANY_NAME'), max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True)
    USER_EMAIL = models.EmailField(_('USER_EMAIL'), unique=True)
    USER_FIRST_NAME = models.CharField(_('USER_FIRST_NAME'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    USER_LAST_NAME = models.CharField(_('USER_LAST_NAME'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    USER_CREATED_DATE = models.DateTimeField(_('USER_CREATED_DATE'), auto_now_add=True)
    USER_MODIFY_DATE = models.DateTimeField(_('USER_MODIFY_DATE'), auto_now=True)
    USER_IS_ACTIVE = models.BooleanField(_('USER_IS_ACTIVE'), default=True)
    USER_IS_ADMIN = models.BooleanField(_('USER_IS_ADMIN'), default=False)
    USER_CITY = models.CharField(_('USER_CITY'), max_length=55, null=True)
    USER_GENDER = models.CharField(_('USER_GENDER'), max_length=1, null=True)
    objects = UserManager()


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'USER_EMAIL'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
        db_table = 'USERS'

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.USER_FIRST_NAME, self.USER_LAST_NAME)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.USER_FIRST_NAME

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.USER_EMAIL], **kwargs)

    def is_staff(self):
        return self.USER_IS_ADMIN
```

Here is my address_add modal.

```
class address_add(models.Model):
    USER_ID = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, db_column='USER_ID',)
    ADDRESS_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ADDRESS_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    FIRST_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    LAST_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    DELIVERY_ADDRESS = models.TextField(blank=True)
    BILLING_ADDRESS = models.TextField(blank=True)
    POSTAL_CODE = models.IntegerField()
    ADDRESS_CREATED_DATE = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ADDRESS_NAME

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'USER_ADDRESS'
```

Here is view.py

```
def create_address(request):
    post = address_add.objects.all()
    users = UsersModel.objects.all()
    address_form = AddressForm(request.POST or None)
    if address_form.is_valid():
        address_form.save()
        return redirect('/login')
    context = {
    'address_form': address_form,
    'post': post,
    'users': users,
}
    return render(request, 'accounts/useraddress.html', context)
```

Here is forms.py

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ADDRESS_NAME = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'name': 'address_name',
        'id': 'id_address_name',
        'type': 'text',
    }))
    FIRST_NAME = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'name': 'first_name',
        'id': 'id_first_name',
        'type': 'text',
    }))
    LAST_NAME = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'name': 'last_name',
        'id': 'id_last_name',
        'type': 'text',
    }))
    DELIVERY_ADDRESS = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'name': 'delivery_address',
        'id': 'id_delivery_address',
        'rows': 4,
        'cols': 6,
    }))
    BILLING_ADDRESS = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'name': 'billing_address',
        'id': 'id_billing_address',
        'rows': 4,
        'cols': 6,
    }))
    POSTAL_CODE = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'name': 'postal_code',
        'id': 'id_postal_code',
        'type': 'number',
    }))

    class Meta:
        model = address_add
        fields = [
            'ADDRESS_NAME',
            'FIRST_NAME',
            'LAST_NAME',
            'DELIVERY_ADDRESS',
            'BILLING_ADDRESS',
            'POSTAL_CODE',
        ]
```

And here is the template.

```
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Adres Ekle</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" id="id_user_id" name="USER_ID" type="hidden" value="{{ request.user.USER_ID }}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="id_address_name" class="control-label">Adres Adı</label>
                  {{ address_form.ADDRESS_NAME }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="id_first_name" class="control-label">Ad</label>
                  {{ address_form.FIRST_NAME }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="id_last_name" class="control-label">Soyad</label>
                  {{ address_form.LAST_NAME }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="id_delivery_address" class="control-label">Teslimat Adresi</label>
                  {{ address_form.DELIVERY_ADDRESS }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="id_billing_address" class="control-label">Fatura Adresi</label>
                  {{ address_form.BILLING_ADDRESS }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="id_mobile_phone" class="control-label">Telefon</label>
                  {{ address_form }}
                </div>-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="id_postal_code" class="control-label">Posta Kodu</label>
                  {{ address_form.POSTAL_CODE }}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Kaydet">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Sorry for the long scripts. I am waiting for the your solutions.
Thanks for now all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `address_add` models USER_ID field is required, you can change that by adding `null=True` and `blank=True` to your `address_add` models USER_ID field.

```
class address_add(models.Model):
    ...
    USER_ID = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, db_column='USER_ID', null=True, blank=True)
```